# Command Line Arguments not Being Read Properly

Tags: c, if-statement, argv, argc

The problem im having is whenever i enter only name of the program, the if statement where the condition is argc == 1 doesn't work and nothing is printed in my command prompt but every other if statement works when i test it.I am really not sure what i have done wrong, thanks for your help.

Also i know the towers function is working correctly because for any other test run i do it prints the correct output, its only when no command line arguments other than the program name is written it does not print anything.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

int n;
int from;
int dest;

if ((atoi(argv[2]) > 3) || (atoi(argv[3]) > 3)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cant have more than 3 towers.");
        exit(1);
} else
if ((atoi(argv[1]) < 0)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cant have negative number of disks.");
    exit(1);
} else
if (argc == 1){
    fprintf(stderr, "No command line argument was given./n");
    n = 3;
    from = 1;
    dest = 2;
} else
if (argc == 2){
    fprintf(stderr, "One command line argument was given\n");
    n = atoi(argv[1]);
    from = 1;
    dest = 2;
} else
if (argc == 4) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Three command line arguments were given\n");
    n = atoi(argv[1]);
    from = atoi(argv[2]);
    dest = atoi(argv[3]);
}

towers(n, from, dest);

exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You had better `#include <stdio.h>`, etc. to include the declarations of the functions.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to put that here when i copy pasted. i already have #include <stdlib.h> 
 #include <stdio.h>  #include "towers.h"

Comment: You need to check argc to know the number of items in argv before you start poking around in it.

Comment: The decision "Cant have more than 3 towers." is based on argv[2]. That seems wrong. Also this would all be clearer if you would replace all this with a `switch(argc) {...}`.

Comment: Note: `atoi` provides *zero* error reporting. Consider using `strtol` with validations.

Answer (score 0):

`argc == 1` means you don't have `argv[1]`, `argv[2]` etc.

So, program will not reach `argc == 1` line as error occurs before the line.

You shuold reorder conditions.

And `argc <= 1` may be good for checking that arguments have not passed.

Comment: You may want to mention the use of `>=` for testing whether arguments are present rather than simply `==`. (of course you can still use the test `==` if you want to force an exact number of arguments be entered)